# Cublic spline extrapolation (R function pchip())

Tags: r

Is it possible to extrapolate some values with the cubic spline method ? From the R function `pchip` documentation:
"`pchip` can be applied to points outside `[min(xi), max(xi)]`, but the result does not make much sense outside this interval."

Hence, isn't the cubic spline meant for extrapolation ? Is there a way to extrapolate without the linear extrapolation ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "The term "spline" is used to refer to a wide class of functions that are used in applications requiring data **interpolation** and/or **smoothing**." Notice that projection or extrapolation is not mentioned.

Comment: This is from `?pracma::pchip`. I took a quit look at Moler (2011), the reference for this method. The book doesn't say much one way or the other about extrapolation ... I think this is better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), have voted to close.